# Why is an array in my service updating an array in my component automatically, while other values are unaffected? (code included)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

https://ufile.io/cc219
sorry about the dl timer - any better upload sites?

I am trying to copy an array located in a service to a component to populate data on my view, however it's behaving inconsistently.

The values of the copied array are changing the items on the view automatically, while other items set individually are not affected.

All of my variables are private and I have no idea what is causing this

Comment: because of line 37 in the code you posted in the question

Comment: could you put up an example that shows the problem on JS Fiddle?  That site is flagged by chrome as a malware site so would rather not chance it.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are reference types. If you pass an array around, the receiver gets a reference to the same array. It's the same fore objects. Primitive values like `number`, `string`, or `boolean` are copied by value, which means the receiver gets a copy of the value instead of a reference.

Comment: Just to add you can copy an array of primatives (containing number, string or boolean) like so: var copiedArray = [].concat(arrayToCopy);  .